# Poetry + Cython + tests (Nosetests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, nose, python-poetry

I use Poetry to build my package with cython extensions. Now I'd like to write tests for it (preferably with nosetest). The problem is that I need to precompile binaries what is usually done with `setup.py build_clib build_ext --inplace`

The best solution for me is to run tests without creating extra `.py` or `.sh` files in the directory as I already have `build.py`. It is ok to run tests after installing the package in virtual environment, like it is implemented on the readthedocs server.

I also got familiar with `taskipy`, so some bash commands in my `pyproject.toml` are also ok. Any other packages that work with `pyproject.toml` are welcome.

Maybe there are any hooks for Poetry, as it cythonizes and comiles while creating `.whl` distribution file.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

**UPD** Tox looks like suitable tool, but it does not see `pyproject.toml` while it in the directory. Links to repos with tox and cython in packages or tutorials are extremely welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extension is part of the distribution, you don't need to do anything besides running `poetry install` - `poetry` will build the extensions in-place as part of the editable installation of your project.

In other cases, you can embed calling `distutils` commands in your tests as part of suite setup/teardown. I'm not very familiar with `nose`, but here's a simple example. Imagine I have a `fib.pyx` (this is an example from the Cython book):

```
def fib(long n):
    '''Returns the nth Fibonacci number.'''
    cdef long a=0, b=1, i
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = a + b, a
    return a
```

A `test_fib.py` module that builds the `fib` library and removes it on tests success:

```
from distutils.dist import Distribution
from distutils.core import Extension
from pathlib import Path
from Cython.Build import cythonize


fib_source = Path('fib.pyx')

# distutils magic. This is essentially the same as calling
# python setup.py build_ext --inplace
dist = Distribution(attrs={'ext_modules': cythonize(fib_source.name)})
build_ext_cmd = dist.get_command_obj('build_ext')
build_ext_cmd.ensure_finalized()
build_ext_cmd.inplace = 1
build_ext_cmd.run()

fib_obj = Path(build_ext_cmd.get_ext_fullpath(fib_source.stem))

# the lib was built, so the import will succeed now
from fib import fib


def teardown_module():
    # remove built library
    fib_obj.unlink()

    # if you also want to clean the build dir:
    from distutils.dir_util import remove_tree
    remove_tree(build_ext_cmd.build_lib)
    remove_tree(build_ext_cmd.build_temp)


# sample tests

def test_zero():
    assert fib(0) == 0


def test_ten():
    assert fib(10) == 55
```

You are probably customizing the `setup_kwargs` in the custom `build.py`. To reuse this code, adapt the `dist` initialization, for example:

```
from build import build

setup_kwargs = {}
build(setup_kwargs)
dist = Distribution(attrs=setup_kwargs)
...
```

#### `pytest` example

Things can be organized a lot more conveniently with `pytest`. Create a file named `conftest.py` with the setup/teardown code extracted to hooks:

```
# conftest.py

from distutils.core import Extension
from distutils.dist import Distribution
from distutils.dir_util import remove_tree
from pathlib import Path
from Cython.Build import cythonize


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    fib_source = Path('fib.pyx')
    dist = Distribution(attrs={'ext_modules': cythonize(fib_source.name)})
    build_ext_cmd = dist.get_command_obj('build_ext')
    build_ext_cmd.ensure_finalized()
    build_ext_cmd.inplace = 1
    build_ext_cmd.run()
    session.fib_obj = Path(build_ext_cmd.get_ext_fullpath(fib_source.stem))


def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    session.fib_obj.unlink()
```

Now the tests become a lot cleaner and the setup code is run once for the whole test session. The above tests example, revisited:

```
from fib import fib


def test_zero():
    assert fib(0) == 0


def test_ten():
    assert fib(10) == 55
```

Comment: Great solution and with pytest everything works fine. Nosetests has same abilities and when I use `setup_module` func in `__init__.py` instead of `pytest_sessionstart` in `conftest.py` with same code it also builds binaries but fails to import them with access denied error. Do you have any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: I suspect the `setup_module` is executed too late (or the import comes too early if you wish). I guess `nose` imports the test modules on collection, so if you have `import fib` on test module level, the import will be executed. Only then the fixtures are executed (btw `pytest` does the same - this is why I put the init code in hooks and not in fixtures).

Comment: The workarounds could include: executing `setup_module` on module level (simply call `setup_module()` in `__init__.py` explicitly), or extract the code from `setup_module` to run on module level (as in my example in the answer). Or the other way: defer the library imports, moving them from module level inside the tests. None of those sounds elegant to me, though.

Comment: I may be wrong though - if this is not the issue, can you add the error trace to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a slight alteration of the accepted answer (pytest example), which now also works when having the src code and test code separated in different directories.

e.g.

```
.
|_ src/
    |_ your_package/
        |_ some_cython_module.pyx
|_ test/
    |_ conftest.py
    |_ some_cython_module_test.py
```

```py
# conftest.py

from distutils.dist import Distribution
from pathlib import Path

from Cython.Build import cythonize


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    difflib_source = Path('src/your_package/some_cython_module.pyx')
    dist = Distribution(attrs={'ext_modules': cythonize(str(difflib_source))})
    build_ext_cmd = dist.get_command_obj('build_ext')
    build_ext_cmd.ensure_finalized()
    build_ext_cmd.inplace = 1
    build_ext_cmd.run()
    session.fib_obj = Path(build_ext_cmd.get_ext_fullpath(
        str(difflib_source.parents[0]) + '/' + difflib_source.stem
    ))


def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    session.fib_obj.unlink()
```